# Can nodejs generate SSL certificates?

Tags: node.js, openssl

I'm writing a proxy support HTTPS-HTTPS proxy. Before i use Python as the main programming language, but i'm interested in node.js now, so i prepare to migrate.

The largest problem i'm facing is that i don't know how to generate CA and other server certificates in node.js. In Python, there is pyOpenSSL which is awesome. I don't find something similar in node.js until now.

Maybe i should use openssl-fork method? But how to handle the interactive operation in openssl.

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In case somebody *does* want to programatically create CSRs from node.js, I have [created a nodejs module](https://github.com/ericvicenti/csr-gen) which uses openssl to create a private key and a CSR.

Edit: Use [pem](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pem) instead. It is much more complete and probably more reliable.

Edit2: Actually, pem is also just a simple wrapper over openssh. For a pure js implementation, look into [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509)

Comment: My module is now totally deprecated. I was only publishing it because I didnt know about pem: https://www.npmjs.org/package/pem

Comment: pem just spawns openssl.

Comment: @andrewrk that's a good thing. High-profile vulnerabilities like heartbleed aside (which never effected node directly), keep security and crypto code as isolated and DRY as possible.

Comment: @DavidSouther Node actually links against a fork of the OpenSSL libraries, generally with a more recent version than what is on the hosting system.

Comment: `node-forge` is a life saver! As far as I know, it's the only option if you also need Windows support.

Answer (score 39):

Use shell for certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem
```

Then use them in node.js

```
var https = require('https');
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem')
},
function (req,res) {
      ... 
})
```

**EDIT:**

You can also give a try to this project in NPM :
https://npmjs.org/package/openssl-wrapper

I found it searching the NPM repo : https://npmjs.org/search?q=openssl

I did not tried or checked it myself, but it looks like a way to generate the certificate using node, which is the original question.

```
var openssl = require('openssl-wrapper');
var password = 'github';

return openssl.exec('genrsa', {des3: true, passout: 'pass:' + password, '2048': false}, function(err, buffer) {
    console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

I'd be interested by a feedback. ;)

Comment: I see no harm in wrapping those shell scripts in in exec functions and a spawn function, and using that instead of a whole library

Answer (score 11):

node-forge allow that. Nothing to say more. DOES NOT use openssl shell command internally.

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509

Comment: This one is great. And most important, it does not depend on "open-ssl"

Comment: I have also used it for production code and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

there is a pure javascript library called "Jsrsasign" to generate CSR certificates.

```
const r = require("jsrsasign");
const kp = r.KEYUTIL.generateKeypair("RSA", 2048);
const csr = r.KJUR.asn1.csr.CSRUtil.newCSRPEM({
 subject: {},
 sbjpubkey: kp.pubKeyObj,
 sigalg: "SHA256withRSA",
 sbjprvkey: kp.prvKeyObj,
});
const privateKey = r.KEYUTIL.getPEM(kp.prvKeyObj, "PKCS1PRV");
```

for more docs visit http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/

Answer (score -3):

None of the node libraries seem to support the options I need, so I use the `openssl` executable.

```
import { execSync } from 'child_process'
import fs from 'fs'
import tempy from 'tempy'

const extHeader = `authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
`
const shell = cmd => execSync(cmd, { stdio: 'pipe' })

const writeCert = (extFile, outfile) => {
  const cmd = [
    `openssl`,
    `x509`,
    `-req`,
    `-in ssl/my.csr`,
    `-CA ssl/root-ca.pem`,
    `-CAkey ssl/root-ca.key`,
    `-CAserial ssl/root-ca.srl`,
    `-out ssl/${outfile}`,
    `-days 1825`,
    `-sha256`,
    `-extfile ${extFile}`,
    `-passin pass:mypassphrase`
  ]
  shell(cmd.join(' '))
}

const createCert = domains => {
  const sans = domains.map((d, i) => `DNS.${i + 1} = ${d}`)
  const ext = extHeader + sans.join('\n')
  const extFile = tempy.file()
  fs.writeFileSync(extFile, ext, 'utf-8')
  writeCert(extFile, 'out.crt')
}
```

Dependencies:

- openssl executable
- yarn add tempy

Comment: This code seems incomplete... What is `ssl/my.csr`, `ssl/root-ca.pem`, etc.? How to generate them? Why not include the code to generate them in the answer?