# When to generate ssl key and cert - for security reasons

Tags: node.js, authentication, https, openssl, pem

I'm looking to generate a `privatekey.pem` and `certificate.pem` for authentication in a nodejs server. I know these [can be generated via OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server) and then saved to a directory, but I also found [pem](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pem) to generate the key and cert on demand.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519707/can-nodejs-generate-ssl-certificates) suggest that either is fine, though more people prefer the OpenSSL way.

Using [pem](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pem) sounds like it's going to be easier, but is there any *security* reason why I shouldn't generate the key and cert on demand in this way?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you want to use a signed certificate, which would need to be generated by the CA.

Comment: @BenFortune Fair enough, but then the question still applies to the private key.

Comment: Well, for me its more a question of correctness. I know OpenSSL private key generation (and related activity like entropy gathering) has been audited. I don't know about the PEM library. In fact, I did not even see a source code download for the PEM library so I could examine the source code. So the PEM library is on the suspicious list for me. Also, the W3C's [WebCrypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) might obsolete some parts of the PEM library.