# How to proxy HTTPS via HTTP without CA or MITM?

Tags: proxy

### HTTP proxy with SSL and DNS support.

I must be lacking some key concepts about proxy-ing because I cannot grasp this. I am looking to run a simply http or https proxy without interfering with SSL. Simply, a fully transparent proxy that can passthrough all the traffic to the browser connected via HTTP or HTTPS proxy without modifying or intercepting any packets. Not able to find any code online or I'm not using the right keywords.

EX. On the browser adding **server.someVPN.com:80 on the HTTP proxy field** and as soon as you try to visit a website, it prompts for authentication. Then it **works perfectly with any domain**, any security, any ssl, no further steps needed. Most VPN providers have this.

How's this possible? it even resolves DNS itself. I thought on transparent proxy the dns relies on the client. Preferably looking for a nodeJS solution but any lang works.

<sub>Please don't propose any solutions such as SOCKS5 or sock forwarding or DNS overriding or CA based MITM. According to HTTP 1.1 which supports 'CONNECT' this should be easy.</sub>

<sup>Not looking to proxy specific domains, looking for an all inclusive solution **just like most VPN Providers** providers.</sup>

----Found the answer too quickly, feel free to delete this post/question admins.

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is that the browser knows it is talking to a proxy server, so for example if the browser want to connect to `https://www.example.com` it sends a `CONNECT www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.1` to the proxy server, the proxy server resolves `www.example.com` via DNS and then opens a TCP connection to `www.example.com port 443` and proxies the TCP stream transparently to the client.

I don't know any solution for nodejs. Common proxy servers include [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), [Apache Traffic Server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/) and [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/).

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT

Comment: can you share your code that triggers the error?
are you sure you pass the TCP stream unmodified?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about, it's the handshake that fails I think. I'm checking this new module, will report soon

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution right after I asked... 
This module works perfectly https://github.com/mpangrazzi/harrier

Does exactly what I was asking for.